# Limit the number of data that save to other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have to tables :

```
tb_document           tb_sentence
=================     ===========================================
|doc_id|document|     | id | sentence_id |sentence | doc_id|
=================     ===========================================
```

I want to take the `document` data from `tb_document`. the data is text and then parse the data become sentences.
I need to store maximum 50 sentences only for every document in tb_sentence.

here's the code :

```
foreach ($content as $doc_id => $sentences){ //$content is variable that save document from tb_document
   $i = 0;
   foreach(preg_split('/\\.\\s*/', $sentences) as $current_sentence){
      $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_sentence SET doc_id = {$doc_id}, sentence_id = {$i}, sentence = '{$current_sentence}'") or die(mysql_error());
      $i<51; $i++;
   }
}
```

but, it still save whole data. please help me. thank you :)

Comment: What is `$i<51` supposed to do?

Comment: @lc. I wanna to store maximum 50 current_sentence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you compare `$i` to 51, but don't do anything with the comparison. Try:

```
foreach ($content as $doc_id => $sentences){ //$content is variable that save document from tb_document
   $i = 0;
   foreach(preg_split('/\\.\\s*/', $sentences) as $current_sentence){
      $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_sentence SET doc_id = {$doc_id}, sentence_id = {$i}, sentence = '{$current_sentence}'") or die(mysql_error());

      if(++$i >= 50) 
          break; 
   }
}
```

The `break` statement will exit out of the `foreach` loop.